# Alternative way to deduce combinatorial identity?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs

By considering the partial fraction decomposition of a certain family of expressions, I have managed to deduce the identity:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {2n\choose k} (n-k)^{2m} \equiv 0 $$

where $n > m$, and  $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

This seems like a surprisingly strong statement. Can this be proven another way?

**Edit**: the expression above closely resembles the formula for the number of surjective functions from $\{1,...,m\} \to \{1,...,n\}$, which is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {n\choose k} (n-k)^{m}$$

Comment: Maybe an inclusion-exclusion counting argument?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is reminiscent. I was just typing an edit to compare another formula, derived using inclusion-exclusion, which is very similar.

Comment: See Exercise 6 **(b)** in [UMN Math 5705: Enumerative Combinatorics, Fall 2018: Homework 4](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/18f/hw4s.pdf). The trick is to extend the range of summation from $\left\{0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$ to $\left\{0,1,\ldots,2n\right\}$ (this just doubles its value for symmetry reasons) and then to use (e.g.) inclusion/exclusion or finite differences.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you very much! If I can ask, for whom is the problem sheet written (as in, what level of student)?

Comment: Advanced undergrad and early grad students; I believe they had seen this trick before, and I was using a "solve 4 out of 7 problems" rule, so I could afford sneaking some sophisticated problems in. [Here is the whole course](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/18f/index.html).